# The value of instance variable taking by default 0,

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Edit(int country_id = 0)       
{  
    tbl_country Data = db.tbl_country.Find(country_id);
    int a = country_id;
    create_tbl_country c = new create_tbl_country();
    c.country_name = Data.country_name;
    c.country_id = 1; // here taking value of c.country_id=0 
    return View(c);
}
```

Comment: `c.country_id = country_id`

Comment: Already tried. whichever value assign, it takes only 0

Comment: Only if you did not provide a value in the url.

Comment: http://localhost:53079/country/Edit?country_id=2

Comment: How to provide value in url

Comment: `/country/Edit?country_id=2` will pass a value of 2 :)

Comment: How we can set url like "localhost:53079/country/2"

Comment: If you using the default routes, change it to `public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)` or create a custom route that has `url: "country/Edit/{country_id}`

Comment: When it comes to HttpPost method, values of c.country_id becomes 0.

Comment: Well did you generate a form control for it?

Comment: no. its simple edit form

Comment: How would you expect it to be posted back if you do not generate a hidden input for it (or a route parameter).

Comment: only value of countryid becomes 0. country_name has a value

Comment: ok got it.. Thanks :) done

Answer (score 0):

change the "country_id" with only "id".